# Unity 3D 360 turning SpaceShip

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I am brand new to Unity, Installed Unity yesterday and want to make a simple game to get myself started...
So I am trying to get a 3D cube to turn by rotation while the up and down moves the cube.

I found out kind of what i was doing following a 2D tutorial online but it seems like it never worked in 3D as my cube instead of rotating around, either tries to tilt over or not move (changing the z y and x on the rotation)

Here is my code, any help would be appreciated or directions to a good tutorial for what i am after would be brilliant!

```
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {
    float maxSpeed = 4f;
    float rotSpeed = 180f;  

    void Update () {
        //ROTATE SHIP
        Quaternion rot = transform.rotation;
        float x = rot.eulerAngles.x;
        x += Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        rot = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, x);
        transform.rotation = rot;

        //MOVE SHIP
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.z += Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * maxSpeed * Time.deltaTime; 
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this line:

```
rot = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, x);
```

to this line:

```
rot = Quaternion.Euler (x, 0, 0);
```

You were taking original x and assigning it back as z;

Comment: Thank you! Man I look dumb haha so simple!  Appreciate this!

Comment: It is making me wait 10 minute to accept a answer, second question, the forward and backwards don't follow the rotation, how can i get this to work?

Comment: @LawrenceWilliamTrigg make a new question about it. But you can achive this easy with using `transform.Translate`. It is hard to answer in comment for that.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help! I am going to try and continue researching and see if i can figure this out first then ask :)

Comment: @LawrenceWilliamTrigg and that is the real coder's spirit :) Usually begginers in new technology don't care about own research. Cheers. TIP: use this Translate method I told you about.